# pygame.mixer.music, I want to play a track as long as while loop is running

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame    
import sys  
import time  
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)

#music files variables
eatsound = ("E:\p\code\eat.mp3")
gameoversound = ("E:\p\code\gameovertrimmed.mp3")
main = ('E:\p\code\mainm.mp3')


playsurface = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game!')

fpscontroller = pygame.time.Clock()

while True: 
    pygame.mixer.music.load(main)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
```

I want to make the sound track to play as a background sound until the end of the loop. But, the while loop doesn't let it do it

Answer (score 2):

Once the

```
  pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
```

Method is called, there is no need to keep calling it over and over inside your while loop

Call it once when you initialize your loop, then stop it once the while loop exit

Comment: I mean the while loop needs to cycle infintly to keep game running so the sound track starts from the beggining again so the track doesnt got to the end

Answer (score 1):

Here's you I understood your question: you want the `while` loop to loop infinitely, so your music plays in the background.

Your problem is that you are calling the `pygame.mixer.music.play()` method in each iteration of the `while` loop. This is not what you want. Instead, I moved this code outside of the `while` loop. Of course, if you leave no code inside the `while` loop, Python will give you an error.

To fix this, you can either put in the `pass` keyword, but instead, you should handle input, which will allow you to close the window.

As a side note, you don't need to put brackets around the strings. You can just define them like this: `music = "path\to\file"`. I also removed the unnecessary import statements, and the line of code which initializes the `Clock`, because they are not needed.

Here is the fixed code:

```
import pygame     

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)

#music files variables
main = 'E:\p\code\mainm.mp3'


playsurface = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game!')

pygame.mixer.music.load(main)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

while True: 
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

I hope you found this answer helped you, and if you have any further queries, please feel free to leave a comment below!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the `pygame.mixer.Sound()`
Here is the working code
`main = pygame.mixer.Sound("E:\p\code\mainmm.wav")

## before while loop

main.play(-1)

while True:
then you code`